# Atom not ignoring *.pyc files added to ignore list

Tags: python, atom-editor

I've added `*.pyc` to the ignored names in the settings but they're still visible in the tree view. Below is my config file:

```
    "*":
  core:
    disabledPackages: [
      "terminal-plus"
      "atom-terminal"
      "term3"
    ]
    ignoredNames: [
      ".git"
      ".hg"
      ".svn"
      ".DS_Store"
      "._*"
      "Thumbs.db"
      "*.pyc"
    ]
  "tree-view":
    hideVcsIgnoredFiles: true
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

Am I doing something wrong? I've also tried `.pyc`

Answer (score 1):

See the discussion on the resolved issue here:

https://github.com/atom/tree-view/issues/50